# Single Socket Programming on Android

Tags: java, android, sockets, client, server

I have been programming on Android for quite some time and have been using sockets for some time too. However, I have never used sockets on Android and I am having an error with this simple line: `sck = new Socket("localhost", 8080);`(android is the client). What could be the reason?

PS: The server address is localhost because I'm on the emulator.

Log Cat Error:

> 03-11 20:39:42.282: E/AndroidRuntime(1819): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   03-11 20:39:42.282: E/AndroidRuntime(1819):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.pconnect/com.example.pconnect.LoginActivity}:
>   android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException 03-11 20:39:42.282:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1819):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
>   03-11 20:39:42.282: E/AndroidRuntime(1819):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
>   03-11 20:39:42.282: E/AndroidRuntime(1819):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 03-11
>   20:39:42.282: E/AndroidRuntime(1819):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
>   03-11 20:39:42.282: E/AndroidRuntime(1819):   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 03-11
>   20:39:42.282: E/AndroidRuntime(1819):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 03-11 20:39:42.282:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1819):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039) 03-11
>   20:39:42.282: E/AndroidRuntime(1819):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 03-11
>   20:39:42.282: E/AndroidRuntime(1819):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 03-11 20:39:42.282:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1819):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>   03-11 20:39:42.282: E/AndroidRuntime(1819):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 03-11
>   20:39:42.282: E/AndroidRuntime(1819):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 03-11 20:39:42.282:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1819): Caused by:
>   android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException 03-11 20:39:42.282:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1819):   at
>   android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
>   03-11 20:39:42.282: E/AndroidRuntime(1819):   at
>   libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84) 03-11
>   20:39:42.282: E/AndroidRuntime(1819):     at
>   libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127) 03-11
>   20:39:42.282: E/AndroidRuntime(1819):     at
>   libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112) 03-11 20:39:42.282:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1819):   at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192) 03-11
>   20:39:42.282: E/AndroidRuntime(1819):     at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172) 03-11
>   20:39:42.282: E/AndroidRuntime(1819):     at
>   java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:566) 03-11 20:39:42.282:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1819):   at
>   java.net.Socket.tryAllAddresses(Socket.java:127) 03-11 20:39:42.282:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1819):   at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:177)
>   03-11 20:39:42.282: E/AndroidRuntime(1819):   at
>   java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:149) 03-11 20:39:42.282:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1819):   at
>   com.example.pconnect.LoginActivity.socketFunction(LoginActivity.java:81)
>   03-11 20:39:42.282: E/AndroidRuntime(1819):   at
>   com.example.pconnect.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:38)
>   03-11 20:39:42.282: E/AndroidRuntime(1819):   at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104) 03-11
>   20:39:42.282: E/AndroidRuntime(1819):     at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
>   03-11 20:39:42.282: E/AndroidRuntime(1819):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
>   03-11 20:39:42.282: E/AndroidRuntime(1819):   ... 11 more

Comment: Please post what error you are getting, we can't read your mind i'm afraid :c

Comment: `I am having an error with this simple line`  Did you forget to include the error in your post?

Comment: The whole app crashes. "Unable to start activity". If I delete this line, the app starts. I was wondering if Android development actually supports Sockets.

Comment: I checked your link. I didn't know about 10.0.2.2 being the AVD's own loopback. Still didn't solve my problem though. I don't need to connect to the AVD, I need a connection to the PC.